# Deserialize a list having extra properties with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want to deserialize the following XML...

```
<MyType>
    <Items>
        <ItemSum>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </ItemSum>
        <Item>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</MyType>
```

...into a type of following structure...

```
[XmlRoot("MyType")]
public class MyType
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public CItems Items { get; set; }

    public class CItems : List<CItem>
    {
        [XmlElement("ItemSum")]
        public CItem ItemSum { get; set; }
    }

    public class CItem
    {
        [XmlElement("Value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, if I try so using C#'s `XmlSerializer`, the `ItemSum` property is always `null`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why do you have classes `CItem` and `CItems` inside class `MyType`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba: No particular reason. Makes no difference where they are placed anyway.

Comment: Something is wrong in the specification. What are you trying to obtain? The XML seems wrong, I think in the <Items> element you should only have <Item> elements. Should the <ItemSum> be outside <Items> ?

Comment: @misha: I know it's a bit weird but I'm working with XML data I cannot specify the schema for. That said, consider the XML definition unchangable, but changes to the structure of `MyType` are possible if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
public class MyType
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemSum", typeof(ItemSum))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(SimpleItem))]
    public CItems Items { get; set; }

    public class CItems : List<Item> {}

    public class ItemSum : Item {}

    public class SimpleItem : Item {}

    public class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way the `ItemSum` is an element of the list and you can know which is it by checking its type.

Edit: You could also make use of computed properties:

```
public class CItems : List<Item>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemSum ItemSum
    {
        get { return this.OfType<ItemSum>().Single(); }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SimpleItem> SimpleItems
    {
        get { return this.OfType<SimpleItem>(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good work-around. But I'd rather have `ItemSum` as a separate property. If no better answer pops up, I will mark yours as accepted.

Comment: I changed your answer a bit to a be more general solution. Thanks for the hint with the computed properties!